# Round-to-floor a list of float numbers?

Tags: python, rounding

I want to round the float numbers in a list to floor in python, I tried `math.floor([i])`, the error is: `a float is required` and I also tried `math.trunc([i])`, I received this error: `AttributeEror_trunc`.
I couldb't find any proper code to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
with open ("G:\Speed\\december.sorted.movement.Sample.txt", 'r') as f:
    firs_line = f.readline()
    split=firs_line.split ("\t")

    Speed = [r.split()[5] for r in f]
    Speedf=[]
    for item in Speed:
        Speedf.append(float(item))

    denominator= 8677.8   
    i = [x/denominator for x in Speedf]

    import math
    v= math.floor([i])
    #print v [:5]
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the floor of each number in list `i`? If so, why not do `v = [math.floor(x/denominator) for x in Speedf]`?

Comment: The standard-library `math.floor` doesn't take lists, unlike `numpy.floor`. This paradigm is true for much of the standard library, as NumPy is Matlab-esque in its acceptance of arrays for functions like `numpy.sqrt`.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use floor division in the first place? `i = [x // denominator for x in Speedf]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`math.floor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor) only accepts a single float value argument (or an object with a `__floor__()` method). To apply it (or another callable taking a single argument) to a whole list you can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as shown below:

```
import math

with open('december.sorted.movement.Sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    first_line = next(f)
    split = first_line.split('\t')

    Speeds = [float(line.split()[5]) for line in f]
    denominator = 8677.8
    v = [math.floor(sp / denominator) for sp in Speeds]
    print(v[:5])
```

If you don't need the `Speeds` list for anything else, you could even combine the two list comprehensions into one and do things like this (although it's less readable):

```
with open('december.sorted.movement.Sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    first_line = next(f)
    split = first_line.split('\t')

    denominator = 8677.8
    v = [math.floor(float(line.split()[5] )/ denominator) for line in f]
    print(v[:5])
```

Comment: Thanks for simplifying my code, I liked how you write it. I tried the code but the floor part doesn't return the correct answer. It just return the float result of the division. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: This is 5 items in Speeds List : [0.6910234249841702, 59.13584700914624, 1.9605857061766796, 2.668716642021207, 1.311176241044252]
And this is what it returns as values in v list: [0.0, 0.006798958261310471, 0.00011523658070017747, 0.00023047316140035494, 0.00011523658070017747]  , all of them should round to 0, but they don't.

Comment: Ahh, I see the problem. Give me a minute and I'll update my answer—it was taking the `floor()` of `speed` not `speed/denominator`.

Answer (score 3):

[`math.floor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor) requires a float value. But you seem to be passing a list of list instead.

You can use list comprehension:

```
v = [math.floor(float(x)) for x in i]
```

That should get a list of rounded values from `i`.

You can also work the `map` function:

```
list(map(lambda x: math.floor(float(x)), i))
```